# Anonying Firewall - Still cannot access banned sites like facebook even via SSH tunnel through SOCKS 5 Proxy

Tags: firewall, socks, ssh-tunnel

I'm in some **un-named** country and I connected to my SOCKS 5 Proxy via an SSH Tunnel which is located in the US. I tried to visit facebook via the browser, but it just times out. But when I ping facebook via the putty terminal i get a reply. I'm not even using the standard 22 port.

I tried connecting to facebook again using the same setup, but this time I'm in *South Korea* and it connects fine. So it's definitely some firewall blocking my request.

How does this Anonying Firewall see what I'm requesting when im connected via a SSH Tunnel using putty?

Comment: Did it pop up a notice about a host key changing or similar ?  I know that (at least China) has done man-in-the-middle attacks on some ssh traffic for quite some years.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably using local DNS instead of doing the name lookup through the proxy.  Your client setting may vary.

I know that Firefox can be adjusted in about:config with the value [network.proxy.socks_remote_dns](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.socks_remote_dns) - true to do name lookups through the proxy, false to use whatever DNS is configured locally.

Other browsers may or may not have an option.

Comment: i configured my socks 5 proxy in Opera 12. Any ideas of what i need to look for?

Comment: I googled "opera browser proxy remote dns", and see a lot of forum threads crying about lack of remote DNS in Opera with SOCKS.  Best bet is to switch browsers or get a socksifier.  It's been a while since I tried using a socksifier, but it was always shaky; I consistently got better results with programs that actually support proxying internally.  I think you'll have a better overall experience if you switch browsers.

Comment: still issues with firefox with proxy setup too.